# How to find an array in another array?

Tags: javascript

These codes don't work:

```
const a = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
console.log(a.includes([1, 1])); // --> false
console.log(a.indexOf([1, 1])); // --> -1
```

This work but I think its not optimized

```
console.log(a.map(x => x.toString()).includes([1, 1].toString()));
// --> true
```

Is there a simpler way ?

Comment: this might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript (if `[1, 1]` are the same reference in memory, then you can find your result using the first two methods)

Comment: Array is one kind of object, both the objects are referring to a different location from the addressing point of view. Compare each element one by one.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(a).includes('[1,1]')`

Comment: Thanks for all answers

Comment: use `a.join(".").indexOf([1, 1])` for optimized solution

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the simplest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const a = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
var index=a.findIndex(x=>{return JSON.stringify(x)===JSON.stringify([2, 2])})

console.log(`item index : ${index}`);
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming this:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'b'];
```

you can invoke:

```
Array.isArray(arr);
```

will return true if the considered variable is an array, otherwise not.

Once you get it, you can apply it to the external array.